# Array of arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is the following correct in javascript:

```
  var candidates = [];
  candidates.push(["Rand","Paul"]);
  candidates.push(["Hillary","Clinton"]);
```

where each element in `a` is itself an array of two strings.

I will be pushing to `a` in a for loop.

Additionally can I iterate over the array as follows:

```
for(var candidate in candidates)
{
    var first_name = candidate[0];
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/barra/7dVer/1/

Comment: Why don't you run and try it?

Answer (score 1):

**You should not use for in with arrays!** If the Array prototype is extended you will run through all new functions there as keys.

You should do:

```
var i, first_name;
for( i = 0; i < candidates.length; i++ )
{
    first_name = candidates[i][0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost. The way you create the arrays is fine, but your understanding of the [for ... in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop is slightly flawed. `candidate` will be the `key` which in the case of an array will be the index. So `candidate[0]` will not work. That is like saying `0[0]`, you would actually need to use `candidates[candidate][0]`. Here is [your JSFiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/7dVer/2/) to show that working, but there are other reasons not to use `for ... in` loop on arrays. When iterating over an array you should use a regular [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < candidates.length; i++){
    var first_name = candidates[i][0];
}
```

Or use [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) in modern browsers (or with a [SHIM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Compatibility)):

```
candidates.forEach(function(candidate){
    var first_name = candidate[0];
});
```

It may also be worth your while to use an object for each of the candidates. That should make things more readable:

```
var candidates = [];
candidates.push({first_name: "Rand", last_name: "Paul"});
candidates.push({first_name: "Hillary", last_name: "Clinton"});
```

Then you can replace the `[0]` with `.first_name`; that's a little more readable.

You will end up with [quite readable, working, code](http://jsfiddle.net/7dVer/3/).

Answer (score 0):

This allows you to iterate through array **keys** or **indices**, so not its **items** :

```
for(var candidate in candidates)
{
    var first_name = candidate[0];
}
```

What you want to do is this :

```
for(var candidateKey in candidates)
{
    var candidate = candidates[candidateKey];
    var first_name = candidate[0];
}
```